# Android options menu set a text

Tags: android, settext, optionmenu

I have an option menu in Android. Now it has got 5 options. When I push one button ther comes up an toast, I push another and it starts an activity. That works all fine. Now I want to add another option. When I choose that option on the emulator I want it to change a text, change the image resource of an imageview, and set the visibility of some textviews to View.GONE in another xml and then start the activity whose layout is that xml file. I do the following:

```
    ...Previous menu options
    case R.id.sample:
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setText("This is the new text");
    tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
    return true;
    following menu options...
```

When I run it on the emulator and I click this option in the option menu it says:"The application example (process com.android.example) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." I already did a project clean, but it doesn't help either. The logcat says:

```
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.example.SampleOption.onOptionsItemSelected(Sample.java:349)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2195)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-25 19:25:19.357: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 19:25:23.127: I/Process(283): Sending signal. PID: 283 SIG: 9
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Forward thanks.

Comment: What is on line 349 in Sample.java along with the few lines preceding line 349?

Comment: In my code there is:

        348. TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        349. title.setText(R.string.titletext);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and set the visibility of some textviews to View.GONE in another xml and then start the activity whose layout is that xml file.

You can't do this. Searching for the `TextView` *tv1* in the other `Activity`'s(simply using `findViewById` will search for that `TextView` in the **current** `Activity`'s layout) layout will not find the `TextView` and this will result on *tv1* being `null`. When you'll try to set the text on it it will throw the `NullPointerException`.

If I understood what are you trying to do, then pass a `boolean` value in the `Intent` that you use to start the new `Activity` and in that `Activity`'s `onCreate` method check the value of that `boolean` value from the `Intent` and then change the visibility of the desired `Views`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

to

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

---

### Edit:

If that doesn't fix the problem, then consider the following scenarios:

1. If your code is *correct*, try deleting the class `R.java` and let Eclipse regenerate it.
2. If your code is *incorrect*, then you might want to double check that all of the ids (i.e. `R.id.tv1`, `R.id.tv2`, etc.) are defined in the appropriate XML file. If the ids are not found, this would result in a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes I thought that too but i double checked them and when I delete R.java and rebuild it the problem won't get away.

Comment: And the wrong variables is just in this example. In my origional code it is the right variable. Excuse me for the wrong example.

Comment: And then after that, you cleaned the project, restarted eclipse, and/or regenerated the `R.java` class and you are still getting a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Can you post your entire `onMenuItemSelected` method and tell us where line 349 is?